# How do I run apt-get on an Azure web app or import cv2 in flask on azure?

Tags: python, azure, docker, opencv

I am trying to import cv2 in a Flask webapp and I get the following message.

```
...
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491189686Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491192986Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491196286Z     __import__(module)
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491199486Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/Webapp/main.py", line 12, in 
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491203086Z     import cv2
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491206386Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in 
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491209886Z     from .cv2 import *
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491213086Z ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-08-16T11:48:08.497759820Z [2019-08-16 11:48:08 +0000] [36] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 36)
2019-08-16T11:48:08.652109211Z [2019-08-16 11:48:08 +0000] [33] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-08-16T11:48:08.652493413Z [2019-08-16 11:48:08 +0000] [33] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

To solve i try running apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev at https://rvvoting.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole but i get this error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

/home>
```

I also tried running the apt-get command on web SSH, but it closes automatically just as i open it

**UPDATE:**

I comment import cv2 from my code, connect to SSH and then run apt-get update then apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev.
then i type import cv2 in python on the ssh and it works.
so i again deploy the webapp by uncommenting import cv2 and the same error is back.

Comment: did you read the official doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019

Comment: I added an update about my issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi there when you ssh into the running app and install like this you are manually updating the 'build' that is the 'deployed build' that's running.

The reason its gone when you re-deploy code changes is the cicd will remake the 'build' and the manual job is not within your build therefore wiping it clean when the deployment gets made.

to add this to your build try the following:

please confirm that you have a .github/workflows/appName(production).yaml file.
If so you will want to update that yaml file with the following

----------------- microsoft Azure default start ------------------
.github/workflows/appName(production).yaml

```
    jobs:
      build-and-deploy
        runs-on: .....
```

----------------- microsoft Azure default middle just after the     - name: Build using AppService-Build ------------------

```
        steps
          - name: install the package that I was doing manually
            run: |
              sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

----------------- microsoft Azure default end ------------------

please give this a go as this is the official way to add packages to your project outside of a pip install requirements.txt